# Cell Broadcast option in HTC Raider ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc, cell-broadcast

I updated my phone to Ice cream sandwich last week. I cant find any option to turn off cell broadcast messages. I have tried everything, looking in call settings, message settings everywhere. I get these annoying messages one after the other!

Can anybody please solve this out? and yes, avoid repeatation that go in call settings or message settings. Its not there!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find this option under `Settings > Call > Cell broadcast`. Where you can enable or disable receipt of cell broadcast messages.

Comment: I already mentioned, its not there.

Comment: @MAezazA.Mirza - As per [HTC Raider guideline - PDF](http://www.cellphones.ca/upload/manuals/htc-raider-4g-manual.pdf), The option is available there.

Comment: yea.. thats the confusion that I cant find tis option on my phone. May be its because of upgrade, I guess.